# how to set specific cell width in different row in apache poi table?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I would like to set the specific cell width in different row in Apache POI table.

I am using the code below to set the cell width but it changes the whole column width. Is there any way I can fix this?

```
CTTblWidth width = cell1.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW();
width.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);
width.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(500));
```

I would like to get this style:

[image: style]

Comment: To build such a table in `Word`, either some columns must be merged or there must be column spanning set in table grid. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647624/how-to-colspan-a-table-in-word-with-apache-poi/34663420#34663420.

Comment: hi @AxelRichter, I have used both merging cell and hiding border also. But I was stuck in row(2).cell(0)   . Please see this image [link](https://ibb.co/b6sgyst) . As you see in that link, row(2).cell(0) width is same as row(0)cell(0)  . I want to reduce the width of row(2).cell(0) . But changing specific cell width always effect on whole column . is there other alternative way ?

Comment: First do determining the whole number of needed columns in the grid. To do so draw all vertical lines trough the whole table. If I counted correct, you will need 8 columns. In first row the first cell spans first three columns, second cell spans next 4 and third cell is the eighth column. In second row the first cell spans 7 columns and second cell is the eighth column. In third row the first cell is the first column, the second cell spans second to fourth columns, third cell is fifth column, fourth cell is sixth column, fifth cell is seventh column and sixth cell is eighth column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generating such a complex table in a `Word` document needs knowledge about how a `Word` table is structured internally.

First do determining the whole number of needed columns in the grid. To do so draw all vertical lines trough the whole table. For your sample table you will need 8 columns.

In first row the first cell spans first three columns, second cell spans next 4 and third cell is the eighth column.

In second row the first cell spans 7 columns and second cell is the eighth column.

In third row and forth row the first cell is the first column, the second cell spans second to fourth columns, third cell is fifth column, fourth cell is sixth column, fifth cell is seventh column and sixth cell is eighth column.

In fifth row all cells are merged.

...

Once you know how the single cells in each row needs spanning the grid, you can determine the column widths of the grid columns. In my following example a default grid column is 6/8 inches width. So the 8 columns fits to 6 inches page width.

Now you can using the given example [How to colspan a table in word with APACHE POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647624/how-to-colspan-a-table-in-word-with-apache-poi/34663420#34663420) for setting the column spans.

While doing this you needs to note that each merging also deletes columns which are not needed anymore. When merging columns in one row multiple times,  one has to recalculate the new column indexes after the removing.

After merging the column widths of the resulting columns needs to be set.

Example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.math.BigInteger;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTable;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableCell;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTcPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTblWidth;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTblWidth;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTVMerge;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STMerge;

public class CreateWordTableMerge {

 static void mergeCellVertically(XWPFTable table, int col, int fromRow, int toRow) {
  for(int rowIndex = fromRow; rowIndex <= toRow; rowIndex++) {
   XWPFTableCell cell = table.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(col);
   CTVMerge vmerge = CTVMerge.Factory.newInstance();
   if(rowIndex == fromRow){
    // The first merged cell is set with RESTART merge value
    vmerge.setVal(STMerge.RESTART);
   } else {
    // Cells which join (merge) the first one, are set with CONTINUE
    vmerge.setVal(STMerge.CONTINUE);
    // and the content should be removed
    for (int i = cell.getParagraphs().size(); i > 0; i--) {
     cell.removeParagraph(0);
    }
    cell.addParagraph();
   }
   // Try getting the TcPr. Not simply setting an new one every time.
   CTTcPr tcPr = cell.getCTTc().getTcPr();
   if (tcPr == null) tcPr = cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr();
   tcPr.setVMerge(vmerge);
  }
 }

 //merging horizontally by setting grid span instead of using CTHMerge
 static void mergeCellHorizontally(XWPFTable table, int row, int fromCol, int toCol) {
  XWPFTableCell cell = table.getRow(row).getCell(fromCol);
  // Try getting the TcPr. Not simply setting an new one every time.
  CTTcPr tcPr = cell.getCTTc().getTcPr();
  if (tcPr == null) tcPr = cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr();
  // The first merged cell has grid span property set
  if (tcPr.isSetGridSpan()) {
   tcPr.getGridSpan().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(toCol-fromCol+1));
  } else {
   tcPr.addNewGridSpan().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(toCol-fromCol+1));
  }
  // Cells which join (merge) the first one, must be removed
  for(int colIndex = toCol; colIndex > fromCol; colIndex--) {
   table.getRow(row).getCtRow().removeTc(colIndex);
   table.getRow(row).removeCell(colIndex);
  }
 }

 static void setColumnWidth(XWPFTable table, int row, int col, int width) {
  CTTblWidth tblWidth = CTTblWidth.Factory.newInstance();
  tblWidth.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(width));
  tblWidth.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);
  CTTcPr tcPr = table.getRow(row).getCell(col).getCTTc().getTcPr();
  if (tcPr != null) {
   tcPr.setTcW(tblWidth);
  } else {
   tcPr = CTTcPr.Factory.newInstance();
   tcPr.setTcW(tblWidth);
   table.getRow(row).getCell(col).getCTTc().setTcPr(tcPr);
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The table:");

  //create table
  XWPFTable table = document.createTable(9,8);

  for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
   for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
    table.getRow(row).getCell(col).setText("row " + row + ", col " + col);
   }
  }

  //defining the column widths for the grid
  //column width values are in unit twentieths of a point (1/1440 of an inch)
  int defaultColWidth = 1*1440*6/8; // 8 columns fits to 6 inches 
  int[] colunmWidths = new int[] {
   defaultColWidth*5/4, defaultColWidth*3/4, defaultColWidth*1/4, defaultColWidth*1/4, 
   defaultColWidth*3/2, defaultColWidth, defaultColWidth, defaultColWidth*2
  };

  //create CTTblGrid for this table with widths of the 8 columns. 
  //necessary for Libreoffice/Openoffice to accept the column widths.
  //first column
  table.getCTTbl().addNewTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(colunmWidths[0]));
  //other columns
  for (int col = 1; col < colunmWidths.length; col++) {
   table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(colunmWidths[col]));
  }

  //using the merge methods and setting the column widths
  mergeCellHorizontally(table, 0, 0, 2); 
  setColumnWidth(table, 0, 0, colunmWidths[0]+colunmWidths[1]+colunmWidths[2]);
  mergeCellHorizontally(table, 0, (3-2), (6-2)); // merge grid cols 3 to 6 but 2 cols are removed already 
  setColumnWidth(table, 0, 1, colunmWidths[3]+colunmWidths[4]+colunmWidths[5]+colunmWidths[6]);
  setColumnWidth(table, 0, 2, colunmWidths[7]);

  mergeCellHorizontally(table, 1, 0, 6); 
  setColumnWidth(table, 1, 0, colunmWidths[0]+colunmWidths[1]+colunmWidths[2]+colunmWidths[3]
                              +colunmWidths[4]+colunmWidths[5]+colunmWidths[6]);
  setColumnWidth(table, 1, 1, colunmWidths[7]);

  mergeCellHorizontally(table, 2, 1, 3); 
  setColumnWidth(table, 2, 0, colunmWidths[0]);
  setColumnWidth(table, 2, 1, colunmWidths[1]+colunmWidths[2]+colunmWidths[3]);
  setColumnWidth(table, 2, 2, colunmWidths[4]);
  setColumnWidth(table, 2, 3, colunmWidths[5]);
  setColumnWidth(table, 2, 4, colunmWidths[6]);
  setColumnWidth(table, 2, 5, colunmWidths[7]);

  mergeCellHorizontally(table, 3, 1, 3); 
  setColumnWidth(table, 3, 0, colunmWidths[0]);
  setColumnWidth(table, 3, 1, colunmWidths[1]+colunmWidths[2]+colunmWidths[3]);
  setColumnWidth(table, 3, 2, colunmWidths[4]);
  setColumnWidth(table, 3, 3, colunmWidths[5]);
  setColumnWidth(table, 3, 4, colunmWidths[6]);
  setColumnWidth(table, 3, 5, colunmWidths[7]);

  mergeCellHorizontally(table, 4, 0, 7); 
  setColumnWidth(table, 4, 0, colunmWidths[0]+colunmWidths[1]+colunmWidths[2]+colunmWidths[3]
                              +colunmWidths[4]+colunmWidths[5]+colunmWidths[6]+colunmWidths[7]);

  mergeCellHorizontally(table, 5, 0, 4); 
  mergeCellHorizontally(table, 5, (5-4), (7-4)); // merge grid cols 5 to 7 but 4 cols are removed already 
  setColumnWidth(table, 5, 0, colunmWidths[0]+colunmWidths[1]+colunmWidths[2]+colunmWidths[3]+colunmWidths[4]);
  setColumnWidth(table, 5, 1, colunmWidths[5]+colunmWidths[6]+colunmWidths[7]);

  mergeCellHorizontally(table, 6, 0, 1); 
  mergeCellHorizontally(table, 6, (2-1), (4-1)); // merge grid cols 2 to 4 but 1 cols are removed already 
  mergeCellHorizontally(table, 6, (5-3), (6-3)); // merge grid cols 5 to 6 but 3 cols are removed already 
  setColumnWidth(table, 6, 0, colunmWidths[0]+colunmWidths[1]);
  setColumnWidth(table, 6, 1, colunmWidths[2]+colunmWidths[3]+colunmWidths[4]);
  setColumnWidth(table, 6, 2, colunmWidths[5]+colunmWidths[6]);
  setColumnWidth(table, 6, 3, colunmWidths[7]);

  mergeCellHorizontally(table, 7, 0, 1); 
  mergeCellHorizontally(table, 7, (2-1), (4-1)); 
  mergeCellHorizontally(table, 7, (5-3), (6-3)); 
  setColumnWidth(table, 7, 0, colunmWidths[0]+colunmWidths[1]);
  setColumnWidth(table, 7, 1, colunmWidths[2]+colunmWidths[3]+colunmWidths[4]);
  setColumnWidth(table, 7, 2, colunmWidths[5]+colunmWidths[6]);
  setColumnWidth(table, 7, 3, colunmWidths[7]);

  mergeCellHorizontally(table, 8, 0, 7); 
  setColumnWidth(table, 8, 0, colunmWidths[0]+colunmWidths[1]+colunmWidths[2]+colunmWidths[3]
                              +colunmWidths[4]+colunmWidths[5]+colunmWidths[6]+colunmWidths[7]);

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("create_table.docx"); 
  document.write(out);
  out.close();

 }
}
```

Result:

[image]