# Vertically merging multiple rows in POI XWPFTable results in malformed table

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a XWPFTable `sampleTable` of size 4x4, and I want first three columns to be merged like [image: this]. However, after running the code here:

```java
XWPFTable sampleTable=sampleDOCX.createTable(4, 4);
             for(int col=0;col<3;col++){
                for(int row=0;row<4;row++){
                    XWPFTableCell cell=sampleTable.getRow(row).getCell(col);
                    if(row==0){
                        cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewVMerge().setVal(STMerge.RESTART);
                    }else{
                        cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewVMerge().setVal(STMerge.CONTINUE);
                    }
                }
            }
```

The table I'm getting is [image: this]. The first two columns are getting their rows deleted somehow.

EDIT: on close inspection, the value `<w:vMerge w:val="restart"/>` isn't added to Cells 0 and 1 of the XML, meaning `STMerge.RESTART` wasn't added to them. Why isn't the tag getting written in them?

Comment: I tried your code but the result is still the same. Only the last column is getting merged, previous merged cells are becoming one-line cells.

Comment: What Apache POI version used? What Word version displays this table?

Comment: Apache POI 5.2.2, LibreOffice 7.3.5.2 on Ubuntu 22.02

Comment: I can see three `restart` and nine `continue` in document's XML, yet the resultant document isn't what it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has following disadvantage: Using `cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr()` the code always adds new `TcPr`. But what if the table cell has table cell properties already? A table cell must have only one `TcPr`.

My code in [How to colspan a table in word with APACHE POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647624/how-to-colspan-a-table-in-word-with-apache-poi/34663420#34663420) considers this. The method `mergeCellVertically(XWPFTable table, int col, int fromRow, int toRow)` always trie to get the `TcPr` first and only if that gets `null` then it adds a new `TcPr`.

But LibreOffice and OpenOffice are own things. As also told in my code in linked answer, LibreOffice and OpenOffice need table grids to fully accept the tables. The aim of the grid is to define the the ratio of column widths. So if the table width is set "100%", then the correct grid widths do not matter. Only the ratio matters.

Complete example again:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.math.BigInteger;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTable;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableCell;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTcPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTVMerge;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STMerge;

public class CreateWordTableMergeTest {

 static void mergeCellVertically(XWPFTable table, int col, int fromRow, int toRow) {
  for(int rowIndex = fromRow; rowIndex <= toRow; rowIndex++) {
   XWPFTableCell cell = table.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(col);
   CTVMerge vmerge = CTVMerge.Factory.newInstance();
   if(rowIndex == fromRow){
    // The first merged cell is set with RESTART merge value
    vmerge.setVal(STMerge.RESTART);
   } else {
    // Cells which join (merge) the first one, are set with CONTINUE
    vmerge.setVal(STMerge.CONTINUE);
    // and the content should be removed
    for (int i = cell.getParagraphs().size(); i > 0; i--) {
     cell.removeParagraph(0);
    }
    cell.addParagraph();
   }
   // Try getting the TcPr. Not simply setting an new one every time.
   CTTcPr tcPr = cell.getCTTc().getTcPr();
   if (tcPr == null) tcPr = cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr();
   tcPr.setVMerge(vmerge);
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The table:");

  //create table
  XWPFTable table = document.createTable(4,4);
  table.setWidth("100%");

  //create CTTblGrid for this table with widths of the 4 columns. 
  //necessary for Libreoffice/Openoffice to accept the column widths.
  //values are in unit twentieths of a point (1/1440 of an inch)
  //first column = 1 inches width
  table.getCTTbl().addNewTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(1*1440));
  //other columns (3 in this case) also each 1 inches width
  for (int col = 1 ; col < 4; col++) {
   table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(1*1440));
  }

  //using the merge methods
  mergeCellVertically(table, 0, 0, 3); 
  mergeCellVertically(table, 1, 0, 3); 
  mergeCellVertically(table, 2, 0, 3); 

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./create_table.docx"); 
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();
 }
}
```

Should lead o following table in LibreOffice too:

[image]

Comment: MS office is able to render the table correctly, but LibreOffice fails to do so on both Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10.

Comment: My screenshot shows LibreOffice rendering the table correctly.

Comment: I created a separate project and ran your code. The table then is created properly. Maybe there's some other problem in my current project. Thanks.

Comment: The culprit is the missing table grid, as told in my answer.

Comment: I tried adding the table grid too, but the result didn't change.

UPDATE: Now the table is rendered perfect. After running the code in separate project and running it again in my original one, the table was rendered properly. Could this be Linux's fault for not updating the file? I was sure to delete the resultant document though, but maybe OS was just undeleting the previous file?